# Auto-retrieve ICollection of complex type with Code First

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, orm

[ Using Code First DbContext with Entity Framework 5.0 RC ]

Not sure what is happening?

- the individual `Tracks` are stored
- and the individual `PlaybackEvents` are stored
- but the `ICollection<PlaybackEvent>` of `Track` is not populated when I do `var tracks = myDbContext.Tracks.ToList();`
- even though I saved with `myDbContext.Tracks.Add(track); myDbContext.SaveChanges();` where `track` had a couple of `PlaybackEvents` in `ICollection<PlaybackEvents>`

#### Hopefully Relevant Parts of Track

```
public class Track 
{
    public string Id {get; set;}

    private ICollection<PlaybackEvent> _playbackEvents;

    public ICollection<PlaybackEvent> PlaybackEvents
    {
        get { return _playbackEvents ?? (_playbackEvents = new List<PlaybackEvent>()); }
        set { _playbackEvents = value; }
    }
}
```

#### Simplified PlaybackEvent

```
public class PlaybackEvent {
    public string Id {get; set;}

    public string Track_Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you see data in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ICollection`, which is your navigation property needs to be declared as `virtual`.

An additional suggestion to your code would be not to explicitly declare your getters and setters for your navigation property, but to move the setter responsibility to the constructor. Making your code look like this:

```
public class Track  
{ 
    public Track()
    {
        this.PlaybackEvents = new HashSet<PlaybackEvent>();
    }

    // Primary key
    public string Id {get; set;} 

    // Navigation property
    public virtual ICollection<PlaybackEvent> PlaybackEvents { get; private set; } 
 }
```

Your `PlaybackEvent` entity also needs a navigation property to enable the **one** Track to **many** PlaybackEvents relationship:

```
public class PlaybackEvent 
{  
    // Primary key
    public string Id {get; set;}  

    // Foreign key
    public string Track_Id { get; set; }  

    // Navigation property
    public virtual Track Track { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Solution! I'll make sure to 1) initialize the ICollection in constructor 2) declare navigation properties in both 3) declare navigation properties as virtual. p.s. looking at the PlaybackEvents table i see two fields, one called Track_Id and the other Track_Id1, but both have identical values, not sure why there is such duplication..